# How do I achieve when I click the cancel button it will revert to the previous page will the data of the user

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

I have a default page, with list view and textboxes with data entry from the user, if he clicks proceed button, it will go to another page, let's say it's a confirmation page. Now if the user, clicks the cancel button the confirmation page, it will go back to the previous page but it should have all the data the user entered, the radio button he/she chooses. Would the be possible to achieve? Would be nice if someone could teach me how to achieve this please. Thank you! This is a web application on vb.net

For easier to imagine, this is my app:
First the user will enter his/her card number and birth year (Take note: this is on default page)

[image]

*There's nothing save on this, as this will just validate the entered data of the user from the database.

Then if it's a valid card number, it will change into this (take note this is still on default page)

[image]

The user then will choose the item he/she would like to purchase then he/she will click the purchase button to go to the next page which is the confirmation page:

[image]

(This is on a different aspx)
This is my dilemma now, when the user clicks the cancel button, it should go back to the default page, together will all his/her information and the item he/she choose to purchase.

Comment: I think the answer to this question lies in what occurs on that conformation page WHEN you confirm? What's supposed to occur? Give that answer, and I suspect we will then have the answer as to how to deal with what to do when the user does not confirm. So, what does the code do when user confirms? Answer that question, and we will no doubt THEN  have the answer how to deal with what occurs when a user cancels on that confirm page.

Comment: _Would this be possible to achieve?_  Short anwser, Yes.  For more detailed help you're going to have to update you question with a whole lot more detail about your project, tools and what you've attempted so far

Comment: What happens WHEN you confirm? do you save the data? If you confirm and save the data, it MUST have already been saved, since we on a different page, right? And since that data either way must have been saved, then when you navigate back to the previous page, you simple have to re-load that data that you MUST have saved,, right? But then again, if on the confirmation page you "yes + confirm", what does your code do? Either way, on the confirm page if you confirm, the data must have been saved, right? So, again: What does the code do WHEN you confirm since the data MUST have been already saved

Comment: As above shows, WHAT occurs WHEN you confirm yes on that 2nd/next page, that answer holds the keys to answering what occurs if you don't confirm, right? So, what does the 2nd page do WHEN you confirm? Answer that question and you quite much have the answer to the first question!

Comment: Hi! I've added some images so it would be easy.

Comment: On 2nd page when you confirm, how does the code know what the user choose and what are you about to confirm? How does code on 2 page remember what you are about to confirm. So, where are you storing the information that you are about to confirm on that 2nd page? Since the code HAS to know what you are about to confirm, then that information must have been saved, right? so, if you hit not confirm and go back, then set a value in session and re-load the information. As I stated, your 2nd page can't know what you about to confirm, so you MUST have saved the information on previous page,but where?

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out WHEN the user enter that information, HOW do you pull the information about how they purchased?

I mean, when we jump to that 2nd page, and you have purchase info, how does it know what purchase info?

I mean, before you jump to that 2nd page, you have to pass the information from the previous page? And how did you pull the information about what was purchased?

As I pointed out, on that 2nd page, HOW IT knows what information about what was purchased is ALSO the answer to your question!

So, before you navigate to the 2nd page, you can go say:

```
  Session("CardNumber") = CarNumber.Text
  Session("BirthDate") = BirthDate.Text
```

So, now on the 2nd page, if the user hits cancel to go back, then on the previous page, you can on first page load check/test and re-load the information

```
  if not IsPostBack then
       if not Session("CareNumber")  is nothing then
            CardNumber.Text = session("CardNumber")
            BirthDate.Text = session("BirthDate")
            // code here to load order based on card number
            // and birthdate
       End if
  End if
```

So, as I stated, you MUST have some way or means to pass the cardnumber and birth date to the 2nd page, else how can you "confirm" the order information?
(answer: you can't).

So, on that 2nd page, you FOR SURE need information about the order etc. You can put that information into session().

So, if they hit the button to go back, then on first page load (IsPostBack = false), then you check for session, and setup cardnumber and birth date, and then run the SAME code you using now to load/display the order.

But, as I stated, you MUST already be passing this information to the 2nd page, else how can the 2nd page "confirm" the order? Right?

This is why I have multiple times asked how does the 2nd page "know" what order and information you are about to confirm? The only possible way would be that you pass the information (cardnumber and birthdate) to the 2nd page. So, if user hits cancel to go back, then cardnumber and birthdate (that you needed on 2nd page) will already have been set by your code BEFORE you jump to that 2nd page.

Comment: I'm just passing the information through global variables but no saving information on the database. Just pure passing of variables.

Comment: You can' t use global variables in a web site. What happens if you launch a 2nd browser? Remember, unlike desktop software, you only have ONE computer - the web server! Global variables will be shared among ALL users of the web site, so with 5 users on web site, then any change to a global variable will effect all users - they ALL will be using the SAME global variables, and thus each user will have a mumbo jumbo of set variables values that are being mixed among and with each user on the web site. Worse yet any un-handled code error re-sets global vars, and so do app pool recycles.

Comment: As a result of above, then ALL OF your software designs must NEVER use global variables since they can't reliably be used. You can freely use code modules, but those code modules MUST NEVER use nor have global variables. Of course, this ALSO explains why I asked how are you in 2nd page dealing with the "knowledge" of what you are about to confirm. So, you have to either pass the values in the URL (as parameter's in the URL as many sites do, or use session()). Session() is per user, and that can be used, but not globals. So on first page, you set session() values before jump to 2nd page.

Comment: Since that 2nd page MUST have and will require knowledge about what you are about to confirm, then it turns out that ALSO is how you can when they hit button to go back to previous page, then on page load, isPostBack = false (the first page load), then you can check for session() values, and if found, then you can fill out the 2 text boxes with those values and also run the code to pull up what they purchased JUST LIKE you do now when they enter their card num and birthdate. The "act" of passing values to 2nd page thus holds solution to your question. Use page load and session as above shows

Comment: I see, I get what you mean. I'll check  Session() with regards to passing data. Thanks for all the information.

Comment: All good, just remember in web land, we can't use global variables, since you have one computer and one web server - and global vars would thus be shared among all users, so in effect they really can't be use as part of your overall design of software. Session() is per user, and limited to one user. And then there is viewstate per the current web page, and thus is again "per user", but only for the current web page, not all of them like session() is. And session is 100% server side, where as viewstate is 100% client browser based.

Comment: Yup, checked mine, I'm using the session. But another question, since the radio button is within the list view, and the way I code is I have to uncheck every radio button on the list view, then will assign the check = true according to the sender,  but how will I do that, if I'm calling the function[RadioButton_CheckedChanged()] from the page load?

Comment: You don't. When the user makes a selection in the gv, you have to save/get/know/enjoy that particular row that the user choose, and once again, that information should be saved in the database. I mean, we need that information over time, and it has to be saved what the user choose here. So, on page load, you load the gv, and then set the correct row based on what they choose. And once again, that row choice MUST have, and HAD TO be saved before going to the next page, right? Once again, the simple answer is how things work on that 2nd page - the row choice user made HAS to be known/saved right

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it is simple follow these steps to acieve this:

1. On first page when user fills the information and click on purchase --> Insert that user's data into a Table in database with one extra column "ConfirmedOrNot" as bit datatype with value "0"(false), then redirect to next page.
2. Now on second page, if the user proceeds then simply update column "ConfirmedOrNot" value to "1"(true),
   If the user clicks on cancel then it will go back to previous page.

Now Here's the solution -> On page load of previous page checks if user's data is already available or not in database if available then fetch data from database and fill on the page,
if data not available then simply leave the page blank.

In your case when user clicks on "Cancel", at that time you would have the data of user in database and when you redirect user on previous page then simply on page load checks the condition mentioned above.
Thanks.